# Targeting correct row elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Sample code:

```html
<tr><td>first_button</td><td>second_button</td></tr>
<tr><td>first_button</td></tr>
<tr><td>first_button</td><td>second_button</td></tr>
<tr><td>first_button</td></tr>
<tr><td>first_button</td><td>second_button</td></tr>
```

```js
function someFunc(i) {

    // first button appears on every row
    first_button[i].style.display="none"; // works

    // second button appears randomly
    second_button[i].style.display="none"; // doesn't work as intended

}

// someFunc(2) targets the third row's "first_button" but
// the last row's "second_button".  I want to target the 
// third row's buttons, not the third button of each type.
```

`var i` is incremented with every row.  I want to target the i-th row's buttons not the i-th button of each type.  What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: How do the `first_button` and `second_button` variables get populated?

Comment: Is there only ever one of `second_button`?

Comment: @gilly3 They're just html elements on a table row.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the rest of the relevant code. You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: @oGeez no there can multiple.

Comment: You should get the i-th row, and then find all the buttons in that row.

Comment: @ColtonAllen - I knew my comment was too ambiguous, so I edited it.  Apparently too late.  :)  I assumed those variables stored references to HTML elements.  Please share the code you use to populate those variables.

Comment: How are you getting the buttons? As @gilly3 requested, please show us the code you use to populate those button variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the rows index, not the index of the nodelist containing your 'buttons'. Also put a check in there to make sure the second cell exists there:

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

function someFunc(i) {
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');

    cells[0].style.display="none";
    if(typeof(cells[1]) != 'undefined'){
        cells[1].style.display="none";
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KWzGQ/1/)

Comment: Check out the [`table.rows` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows) and the [`row.cells` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement).  Using the built in collections is cleaner, and avoids selecting rows from nested tables.  [jsfiddle.net/KWzGQ/2](http://jsfiddle.net/KWzGQ/2/)

Comment: @gilly3 Thanks, I'll take your advice and use the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using some `document` method to get references to your buttons.  Maybe `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`.  Those methods are also available on individual elements.  So, you can get a reference to the `<tr>` element and call `row.getElementsByClassName()` to get just the elements that are descendents of the row.